# Print scaling different in Mathematica 11

Tags: printing, display

I have a couple instances where I need to print out a programmatically generated graphic at a *specific* size.

Here's an example graphic:

```
toprint = 
 Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 4], 
   Text[Style["TEST", FontSize -> Scaled[.3], Underlined, Bold]]}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

In Mathematica 10, I could easily print this to size (2 inches in diameter for this example) by using:

```
NotebookPrint[Show[toprint, ImageSize -> 2*72], Interactive -> True]
```

In Mathematica 11, I've noticed this is no longer the case. After some trial and error, I've realized I have to multiply the size in inches by `100` to get the correct size, not the traditional `72`. Any ideas on the change?

I'm running a Retina MacBook Pro.

```
$Version

"11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)"
```

Comment: On Windows 7 x64 I get almost identical results with versions 11.0.1 and 10.4.1. So this may be OS-specific.